# File path for android when using emulator

Tags: android, download

I am new to android. I am trying to download a file from server and save the file in a particular path. The application is working fine. However I am not able to find the path of the downloaded file. In the code I have given as

File output = new File("/data/data/com.test.firstApp/", fileName);

Where can i find the file on my system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use hard coded file paths.  The framework will give you the base path of the area you want to save files to.

For the SD card, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

For local files, use `Context.getFilesDir()` (or `Context.openFileOutput(String name, int mode)`, etc)

For local cache, use `Context.getCacheDir()`

Comment: I agree to u and I used the getFilesDir(). The app worked fine even now. My question is  - My android emulator downloaded file from server and stored at getFilesDir() path. Where is this path on my computer? I want to open the file that I have downloaded in a notepad.

Comment: getFilesDir returns a File object.  On this File object, log the String value of File.getAbsoluteFilePath, and that will tell you the full absolute path to the root directory.

Comment: I got the path in this form: /data/data/com.test.firstApp/files/test_123.wav. So where will I find it on my system?

Comment: Not sure what "on my system" means.  The emulator uses a virtual storage that isn't directly mapped to a folder on your computer's hard drive.  To get at that file, open up an "adb shell" session at the command line.  You can browse the emulator's virtual storage using the usual unix/linux commands (cd, ls, ...), and you can copy it onto your computer's local storage using "adb pull" command

Comment: Brilliant dude. Thank you soooooooo much. This is what I was searching for. I found the file. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Rich's answer, in the likely event you will end up writing to external storage make sure to include this permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You can find there many methods how to save file. What is more you can also read something about good practices.

Cheers